# Exception Handling for Files

Tags: c++, file, exception

If a program tries to use my file-reading class to access part of a file that does not exist (i.e., is after ios_base::end), what exception should be thrown?

I was going to use std::out_of_range, but now I'm beginning to think std::runtime_error would be more appropriate.

Edit:

The interface works a bit differently than the standard `fstream` class in that it's based around `for` loops rather than `while` loops.  So instead of doing the following:

```
while (MyFile.peek() != EOF)
{
    char Character = MyFile.get();
    // Do stuff with Character.
}
```

The user of the class can do this:

```
for (std::streampos Pos = 0; Pos < MyFile.GetCharCount(); Pos++)
{
    char Character = MyFile.GetChar(Pos);
    // Do stuff with Character.
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're providing an array-like interface (using operator[], rather
than get), then throwing `std::out_of_range` is a good idea; a better
idea in this case might be to figure out how many bytes you can actually
access, furnish a size() function, and make being in range
a pre-condition.  (Of course, to provide random access like this, you're
going to have to read the entire file into memory anyway.  You can't
seek to arbitrary positions at random in a text file, except under
Unix.)

If you're providing a file like interface, then setting an error status,
like iostream does, is the preferred solution.

If you're providing neither, it's all a question of what you are
providing, and what user expectations for it are, or should be.

Answer (score 5):

Don't throw an exception, do like the standard library does and set an "end-of-file" flag. Only throw an exception if it's really super duper *unexpected* that something happened.

Comment: See my edit; An EOF flag doesn't really make sense in this case.

Comment: @Maxpm: So it's more like you have an array of `char`s, huh? Then you got some possibilities: Just don't allow it and throw an exception, like your original proposal, and for that case `out_of_range` is more suited, or just return the `EOF` character. Or maybe even just return the last character in the array.

Answer (score 1):

How are they getting to the point of reading past the end of the file? If they're simply reading to the end of the file, and then continuing to read, I'd simply signal EOF. If they're seeking to beyond the end of the file, the attempt at seeking should fail, so they never get to the point of trying to read from there.

I would not, however, imitate the normal iostreams too closely. In particular, when/if reading reaches the end of the file, I would *not* set a "sticky" bit that prevents further reading from the file until it's cleared. It's quite reasonable and normal to write a file in one process, and read it in another concurrently, so reaching the end of a file can be a temporary condition.

Comment: The interface has functions like `GetChar()` and `GetLine()`, which take positions in the form of `std::streampos` arguments.  I also include `GetCharCount()` and `GetLineCount()` functions, so a file can easily be read in a `for` loop rather than a `while` loop.  (i.e., with `CurrentPos < MyFile.GetCharCount()` as the conditional.)

Comment: @Maxpm: This sounds like you're letting them treat a file almost like a random access collection. In that case, I think `out_of_range` is probably the more meaningful/suitable choice.